# difference between ${CDR(start)} and ${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)} in asterisk

Tags: time, asterisk, voip, phone-call, ivr

I have created a dialplan which takes the call and save the start and end time of the call. I used `${CDR(start)}` to get the start time of the call but when I used `${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}` instead it gave me a 10 or more seconds difference as compared to `${CDR(start)}`.Part of my code:

```
same => n,NoOp(------${CDR(start)}----${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}--)
```

the above line is second line in my dialplan.From the docs `${CDR(start)}` give start time of call and `${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}` gives current time .But I place the line as second line of my dialplan so its nearly start of call so both `${CDR(start)}` and `${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}` should be equal approximately but the output was like

```
NoOp(------2015-10-25 12:30:10----2015-10-25 12:30:21--)
```

Why there is so much diffrence in both? and also I dont know why the value of `${CDR(end)}` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${CDR(start)}` - is a time of call start.
`${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)}` - **current** time, when this command was executed.

If you use `EPOCH` variable after hangup, it may points to the end of call.

`${CDR(end)}` can be empty if call is active now and will be filled after hangup.

About CDR variables: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/CDR+Variables

Comment: I dint have a dial command before the code that I posted and I got the `${CDR(start)}` but you are saying `it is a time of call start, when dial() was executed.`

Comment: Instead of `dial()` it also can be incoming call or some internall call (ex. from AMI or callfile). Anyway, it is a time of current call start.

Answer (score 1):

${CDR(start)} is not time of current call start, but time of current cdr start. It can be changed after transfer from queue, ResetCDR, ForkCDR command

EPOCH always give current linux time. After hangup it can show end of call, but also can show different time if processing was long enoght.